# onmouseup or addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have a question which I still haven't found the answer to.

When I use this method to capture a mouse up event:

```
<div onmouseup="/*Script to be executed*/"></div>
```

Is that more efficient than this newer method:

```
<div id="Id"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("Id").addEventListener("mouseup", function () { /*Code to be executed here.*/ });

</script>
```

Or not?

Everyone I know uses addEventListener and I'm the only one using onmouseup. So to settle a little dispute, which method of capturing mouse up events is *faster*?

Cheers,
Oscar

Comment: It's generally best practice to separate your logic from your dom because it's easier to maintain.

Comment: @smerny, So you think addEventListener wins over onmouseup because it's more efficient to separate javascript from html. But javascript has been embedded into html for the longest time, why did they not think of that before? And why is it more efficient to separate the two languages?

Comment: I don't believe there would be a real difference in speed... it's more about readability and maintainability. I always cringe a bit when I see javascript directly on the dom objects.

Comment: Ah, so you're not sure which is more efficient. Well I take your point about aesthetics, though I don't care much for it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "why did they not think of that before", as addEventListener exists for years (over a decade, I believe). It won't work on IE <=8, you'll have to use the similar, IE-only, attachEvent instead. Also, addEventListener and attachEvent allow you to attach multiple listeners to the same element.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, you can setup tests, but I doubt using one over the other would have any meaningful performance benefits.

Comment: @bfavaretto, it's a bit scattered to have addEventListener in script as well as onmouseup in html. Why they did not create a consistent, disciplined, efficient and overall better format for programming is beyond me.

Comment: Oscar, the history of web scripting is made of several layers. addEventListener came later, but removing the former methods is never an option because that might "break the web".

Comment: @bfavaretto, We don't "break the Web", we deprecate. And we should have deprecated the less consistent onmouseup method when addEventListener came out. It's confusing to have both. I was under the impression that you could use both methods so I used the less efficient/easier method (Yes, onmouseup is the slower method), which isn't a good idea if you want to be a pro coder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are equally fast, or if not they are so close it doesn't matter one way or another. The goal is readability.

Suppose you have a card game and you want to drag the card on screen around using the new html5 drag and drop api.

You could write:

```
<div id="card_1" ondragstart='function(this);' ondragenter='function(this);' ondragover='function(this);' ondragleave='function(this);' class='card'></div>
```

Or you could write this:

```
function initialize_event_listeners(){
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
    for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        cards[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function, false);
        cards[i].addEventListener('dragenter', function, false);
        cards[i].addEventListener('dragover', function, false);
        cards[i].addEventListener('dragleave', function, false);
    }
}
```

Now say you had 10 cards, and you wanted to drop the native drag and drop support and use something else. In that scenario which would you rather use? Personally I would take the function...

Comment: Fair Enough. I thought one might be more efficient.

Comment: I think a more important distinction is that "addEventListener('dragstart', ...)" does just that. It ADDS one. Saying "ondragstart = something" means that "something" is now the ONLY event dragstart listener on that element. This may very well not affect your use case, but def an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and this might be wrong - which doesn't help you with your dispute) the addEventListener method is more efficient - if so slightly as to make no difference at all. This is because the onmouseup inline method is merely a shortcut to addEventListener. In other words, it is shorthand that points to the same function and sort of writes the addEventListener code in the background anyway. But in general practice it is better, in my opinion, to have your logic separate from your structure for easy reading sake as well as debugging.

Comment: Correctimundo :) Thanks.